# How to get every combination of a combolist

Tags: combinations

I have a program where you can import a combolist, ex.

```
test:lol
hello:hi
sup:hey
```

The first one being the "username" and last one being the "password".
I want so that every single username will have a line with each password of the list. I would like all of this put into a separate string list.

Such as:

```
test:lol
test:hi
test:hey
hello:lol
hello:hi
hello:hey
sup:lol
sup:hi
sup:hey
```

I think this might be a really simple code, something to do with first separating the list into two lists, then for each username, add every password, but my brains can't really think of anything to come up with a solution for this.

thank you in advance :)

Comment: You could put them in separate tables, and "select * from a, b"..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're right. 
Firs - get two lists `users` and `passwords` by separating each string by column.
Second traverse `users` and `passwords` and combine them. In pseudocode

```
foreach uName in users do
    foreach pwd in passwords do
        print user.concat(":").concat(pwd)
    end
end
```

Explanation:

```
Get first `uName` from `users`
    Get first `pwd` from `passwords`
        output "`user`:`pwd`"
    Get second `pwd` from `passwords`
        output "`user`:`pwd`"
    ...
Get second `uName` from `users`
    Get first `pwd` from `passwords`
        output "`user`:`pwd`"
...
```

Feel free to ask, if something left unclear

Comment: Thanks bro, great explanation! :)

Comment: @CoffeeClient You're welcome. If you found my answer helpful - please mark it and, if you think it's worth, upvote

Comment: Martynenko would upvote but need 15 rep, but thanks :)